# If a gem is not listed using the following command, does that mean it's not installed?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

For example, I'm trying to find out whether RubyGems is installed, so I tried `gem query --name-matches rubygems` to come up with nothing. `gem query` resulted in a list that did not list RubyGems. Is my guess correct so far?

Comment: rubygems isn't a gem.  it would be difficult to install it if it were...

Comment: @MarkReed: I realized it shortly after asking the question.

Comment: I can see why some people might mistakenly think rubygems is a gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if it's installed:

```
gem list bundler
```

Gives:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.3)
```

To find the gem source code:

```
gem which bundler
```

Gives:

```
/path/to/directory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what gems are installed locally, use `gem list <pattern>`. Leave off the pattern if you want to list all the gems.

If you're talking about RubyGems itself, the fact that you can run the `gem` command indicates it's already installed. You can do a `gem -v` to see the actual version.